# MapBox marker offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, marker, mapbox

I'm using the MapBox SDK for iOS and encountered a problem I can't find a good solution for.
In the iOS the MKAnnotationView allows me to do the following:

> ```
>         view.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -15);
> ```

Is there a MapBox RMMarker equivalent for this?

So basically I need to move the marker a few pixels up from its original position, taking the zoom level into account as well. (So when you zoom, the marker's bottom part keeps fixed on the same point)

As you can guess, there's a little arrow at the bottom of my marker that I want to have pointing to the GPS position in question, but the RMMarker seems to center on this point right now rather than being positioned on top of it, like I'd need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On mapbox it's proportional bwn 0 - 1.0;

So if we want it centered it would be

```
CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
```

Use this:

`- (id)initWithUIImage:(UIImage *)image anchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint`

```
RMMarker * marker = [RMMarker initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] anchorPoint:CGPoint(0.5,1.0)];
```

If you want the bottom of the image to point to the location, I think you'd want either 1.0 or -1.0 as your Y point.  I don't have a MapBox proj available right here to test it.

[See Docs Here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MapBox/1.0.3/Classes/RMMarker.html#//api/name/initWithUIImage%3aanchorPoint%3a)

Comment: This is the answer, just tested it out. Thanks!
Just replace the CGPoint with CGPointMake