# Android MapBox marker offset

Tags: android, mapbox

I have to set marker offset to bottom (center is by default). I found how to do it on JS or iOS, but how to do it in Android?

JS - http://bl.ocks.org/andrewharvey/01006319700c5352deaad3b58ec53b8c

iOS - [MapBox marker offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561998/mapbox-marker-offset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property called Anchor for marker based on their [Doc](https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-markers/)

I haven't used it yet, but you should be able to do:

```
new MarkerViewOptions().anchor(0.5f, 1.0f)
```

Hope this helps:)

---

**EDIT (28Dec2017)**

Mapbox sdk v5.2.0 deprecates `MarkerView`, users are advised to leverage `SymbolLayer` instead. 
Please refer to https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/9782

Comment: It is now deprecated, what is the new way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

i find the following centres the marker

```
new SymbolLayer(<layer-id>,<source-id>)
  .withProperties(
    ...
    iconOffset(new Float[]{0f, 12.5f})
    ...
   ));
```